# At click route to details of given object

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have two components: recipe and recipe-detail.
Recipe is displaying list of recipes from my database and recipe-detail should display details of given recipe. What I want to achieve is to whenever someone click on recipe name I want to route him to recipe-detail component.
This is my recipe html:

```
<section class="columns">
    <div class="column" *ngFor="let recipe of RecipeList">
        <h2><a routerLink="recipes/{{recipe.Id}}" routerLinkActive="true">{{recipe.name}}</a></h2>
        <p>{{recipe.recipeBody}}</p>
    </div>
</section>
```

My routing file:

```
{path:'recipes', component: RecipeComponent},
{path: 'recipes/:id', component: RecipeDetailsComponent}
```

And my recipe-detail ts:

```
export class RecipeDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() recipe! : any;
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private sharedService: SharedService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getRecipe();
  }
  
  getRecipe() : void{
    const id = Number(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'));
    this.sharedService.getRecipeById(id).subscribe(recipe => this.recipe == recipe);
  }
}
```

Simple html for test:

```
<h2>Name : {{recipe.name}}</h2>
<h2>RecipeBody: {{recipe.recipeBody}}</h2>
<h2>IntendedUse: {{recipe.IntendedUse}}</h2>
<h2>CoffeeId: {{recipe.coffeeId}}</h2>
```

Results:
When I click on recipe name (recipe.component) it redirects me to: http://localhost:4200/recipes/recipes  when it sould be for example http://localhost:4200/recipes/1

And in the console i get: **TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')**

Edit:
How i fetch it:

```
getRecipes() : Observable<any[]> {
    return this.http.get<any>(this.ApiUrl + '/Recipes')
  }
  getRecipeById(val:any){
    return this.http.get<any>(this.ApiUrl + '/Recipes/', val);
  }
```

Comment: Do you see `id` being passed to `this.sharedService.getRecipeById(id).subscribe` ? please confirm

Comment: @ShashankVivek I have switched my method to yours and in debug i get: const id = "recipes". I guess that because I still have http://localhost:4200/recipes/recipes url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend doing it as below by subscribing

HTML

```
<h2><a [routerLink]="['/recipes', recipe.Id]" routerLinkActive="true">{{recipe.name}}</a></h2>
```

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,private sharedService: SharedService) {

ngOnInit() {
 this.route.params
      .subscribe(
        (params: Params) => {
         this.sharedService.getRecipeById(params['id']).subscribe(recipe => {
            this.recipe = recipe;
          })
        }
      );
    }
}
```

or even make it better with [switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap)

Comment: I have switched my method to yours and in debug i get: const id = "recipes". I guess that because I still have localhost:4200/recipes/recipes url. How do I fix that routing problem?

Comment: @Griefing: check the HTML code in my answer and let me know

Answer (score 0):

You need to use = to assign the values but not ==.

From:

```
this.sharedService.getRecipeById(id).subscribe(recipe => this.recipe == recipe);
```

To:

```
this.sharedService.getRecipeById(id).subscribe((recipe:any) => this.recipe = recipe);
```

Comment: Oh damn typo. It kinda? works now but still getting undefined (reading 'name')

Comment: use console.log(recipe) to check its value.

Comment: It shows undefined

Comment: That's why u cant get its name, it need to be an json obejct @Griefing

Comment: I am fetching it the same way as the list so I don't see a problem there